# Project latest price back and check where previous price intersects it

Tags: pine-script

Working with Trading View's Pine Script - How can I take the latest high price (from the latest bar) and plot a constant horizontal line back to check when historically the highs were above this latest high?

The following code projects the latest high, but I am struggling to find a way to test where previous highs were above this line. Is there maybe a way to make this last value a proper constant and to project it back or are there other alternatives?

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

var line _lpLine = line.new(0, 0, 0, 0, extend=extend.left, style=line.style_dashed, color=color.yellow)

_lastTradedPrice = high
line.set_xy1(_lpLine, bar_index-1, _lastTradedPrice)
line.set_xy2(_lpLine, bar_index, _lastTradedPrice)

test = high > _lpLine ? 1 : 0

plot(test, color=color.green)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good to use the operator `for`, but in this case it is necessary.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (My Script)", overlay=true)

lb = input(100, 'look back', minval=1)

var line  _lpLine = line.new(0, 0, 0, 0, extend=extend.left, style=line.style_dashed, color=color.yellow)
var label  lbl    = label.new(na, na, style=label.style_xcross, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
var        index  = lb
var        flag   = false

_lastTradedPrice = high
line.set_xy1(_lpLine, bar_index-1, _lastTradedPrice)
line.set_xy2(_lpLine, bar_index, _lastTradedPrice)

// test = high > _lpLine ? 1 : 0

// plot(test, color=color.green)

for i=1 to lb
    if high[0] < high[i]
        index := i
        flag  := true
        break

if flag
    label.set_x(lbl, bar_index - index)
    label.set_y(lbl, high)
    flag := false
    index := lb
else
    label.set_x(lbl, na)
    label.set_y(lbl, na)
    index := lb
```

[image]

ADDED a second version of the program that marks all values above the last closing line and finds the highest value among them.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (My Script) v2", overlay=true, max_labels_count=100)

lb = input(100, 'look back', minval=1)

var line  _lpLine = line.new(0, 0, 0, 0, extend=extend.left, style=line.style_dashed, color=color.yellow, width=2)
label  lbl    = label.new(na, na, style=label.style_xcross, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
var        capture = float(na)

_lastTradedPrice = high
line.set_xy1(_lpLine, bar_index-1, _lastTradedPrice)
line.set_xy2(_lpLine, bar_index, _lastTradedPrice)

for i = 1 to lb
    if not na(lbl[i])
        label.delete(lbl[i])

capture := 0
for i=1 to lb
    if high[0] < high[i]
        lbl := label.new(bar_index - i, high[i], style=label.style_xcross, color=color.red, size=size.auto)
    if capture < high[i]
        capture := high[i]

plot(capture, color=color.blue, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3, show_last=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. Is there a way to get the value of high at the intersection point and to plot only such high values that are intersected? I also noticed that this approach only catches the last value, but not the rest of them further away.

Comment: The value `high[i]` can be stored in a loop, in the same place as the value `index`. As you leave only the last line, I leave only one intersection, otherwise everything will be in crosses.

Comment: You can also find and save all the points of intersection with the last line, but you will need to use `array` to store information. But you need to determine how far back to look for the intersection points and what to do with them later.

Comment: Appreciate your help. high[i] does not seem to be stored when I add it into a variable and removing "break" in the loop to show all intersections removed them all. How would you store all these points in an array and then plot them?

Comment: Using arrays is a non-trivial task to discuss within the scope of this question. Try writing a script with arrays yourself and ask a new question if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following based on AnyDozer's approach to mark ALL values with high > last high with a cross, but this only marks the first 3 or so and not all. What would be wrong here? Additionally, I am trying to capture all these high values in the variable "capture" and to plot just them. All other values of "capture" should be just na.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (My Script)", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500)

lb = input(10)

var line  _lpLine = line.new(0, 0, 0, 0, extend=extend.left, style=line.style_dashed, color=color.yellow)
lbl    = label.new(na, na, style=label.style_xcross, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
var        index  = lb
var        flag   = false
capture = float(na)

_lastTradedPrice = high
line.set_xy1(_lpLine, bar_index-1, _lastTradedPrice)
line.set_xy2(_lpLine, bar_index, _lastTradedPrice)

for k=0 to lb
    for i=0 to lb
        if high[0] < high[i]
            index := i
            flag  := true
            label.set_x(lbl, bar_index - index)
            label.set_y(lbl, high[i])
            capture := high[i]
            break
            
plot(capture)
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your help! Is it possible to take this last capture value and make it into a series that is constant for the whole chart? If this last value is 500 for example, is it possible to make it the same 500 for every bar so it is a constant series this way?

Comment: You can draw a line at the level of this value.

Comment: I would need to add further calculations with this value for previous bars. Pine Script cannot take this last value and project it back as a constant?

Comment: This value is found on the last bar, you will not be able to use it for calculations on previous bars.